# Can dielectric grease be used on aluminum wire?

Tags: electrical, aluminum-wiring

Can dielectric grease [like this one](https://www.crcindustries.com/products/technician-grade-dielectric-grease-3-3-wt-oz.html) be used with aluminum wire? (in place or in combination with black dioxide paste) to stop the oxygen in the air from harming the aluminum?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? I don't think dielectric grease is either conductive or abrasive...

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. As asked above, what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well, I didn't have the paste on hand but had the grease and wanted to use it instead (or in combination for 'double' protection). Def don't see how this would be an XY problem.

Comment: It is non-conducting.  That's why it's called Dielectric Grease.

Comment: Does the paste's instructions say it is made to be used for lug connections to large size aluminum wires? NEC 110.3(B) is clear that products must be used according to their instructions.  110.2 also requires they be approved by an NRTL for use in electrical.  I.E. a UL Listing.  So if you need to use goop, don't use the wrong goop because you don't have the right goop.  In fact goop is not required for AL lug connections.

Answer (score 1):

The data sheet linked with the product indicates no restrictions. As the product is intended to be used in electrical-related-environments, some of which would be aluminum wire, one can expect no complications. Dielectric products are engineered to be inert (non-reactive) in order to provide the electrical characteristics desired of such a product.

I have no reference for combining it with black dioxide paste. My primary experience is with silicone dielectric grease.